# styling on ion-button with disabled not working in ionic V4

Tags: css, ionic4

I am using ionic v4, and I have to gave a different color when button is disabled as we normally do. But whatever I applied didn't show any effect. As ion button does not have any background-disable property as it has for hover, focus and active.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-custom-properties

Here is my code:

```
 <ion-button type="submit" color="danger" disabled="true">Next</ion-button>
```

I have tried the following things:

```
css in variable.scss (approach 1)
---------------------------------
:host(.button-disabled) .button-native{
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

css in my custom file (approach 2)
----------------------------------
ion-button[color='danger'].button.button-disabled{
  background: blue !important;
  --background: blue !important;
  --opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the color conditionally in the html depending on the disabled value:

```
<ion-button type="submit" [color]="isDisabled? 'danger':'primary'" [disabled]="isDisabled">Next</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Since Ionic v4 :

Using the `:disabled` CSS selector to target a disabled `ion-button` will not work as it only works on activable/focusable elements like a `button` or an `input`, instead, you have to use `[disabled]` (I don't think relying on the `.button-disabled` class set by Ionic is a good practice).

If you haven't set the `color` attribute of your `ion-button`, you can simply change the `--background` CSS property.

But, if you have set the `color` attribute of your `ion-button` (e.g. `<ion-button color="danger">My button</ion-button>` you can't changed the background color using the `--background` CSS property, instead you have to use the `--ion-color-base` with `!important` (you don't have the choice since Ionic have defined their CSS property with it).

### Here is a full example :

```html
<ion-button color="danger" [disabled]="true">
  My button
</ion-button>
```

```css
ion-button[disabled] {
  --ion-color-base: #b34d5a !important;
}
```